# Query String is not appending when am using the e.preventDefault()

Tags: php, jquery

```
//Jquery 

// I used the below Jquery for slide down the Div its working fine with e and   //
//e.preventDefault(). If am using that it just slidedowns and not displaying the 
//content i //mean the query string


$(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {
    $("#edititems").hide().slideDown('slow');
e.preventDefault()
});


//hyperlinks for same page
```

// I used the below Jquery for slide down the Div its working fine with e and   //
    //e.preventDefault(). If am using that it just slidedowns and not displaying the 
    //content i //mean the query string

```
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=1' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=2' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=3' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=4' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>


//Div which holds php statements that echo outs some values   

<DIV id='edit_inven' style="display:none">
echo $_GET['pedit'];
</DIV>
```

Comment: Why would it, that's what preventing the default action of the anchor is supposed to do.

Comment: you have already prevented its default behaviour.!

Comment: Preventing the default action is supposed to prevent the anhor from reloading the page and changing the URL, so it's what you'd expect. If you need to load data from the server without reloading, you have to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault() is Preventing the Default Behavior of your a tag

```
<!-- Default behavior upon clicking is to go to index.php. If you prevent the default, clicking does nothing unless otherwise specified -->
<a href='/index.php'>Link!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the echo with php tags

```
<?php echo $_GET['pedit']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.history.pushState("", "", '/newpage');
```

in your code like

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {
    $("#edititems").hide().slideDown('slow');
    window.history.pushState("", "", $(this).attr('href')); // here
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: I tried to c wat exactly (this).attr('href') contains its showing the url and the query string appended to it but while am trying to access the query string from php its not able to take the query string.

Comment: I kept the code which u suggested me but its showing in the url along with the query string but when am trying to access the query string its not treating dat as a query string (in the same page i used if(isset($_GET['pedit_id']) {} else {} its executing the else block)

Answer (score 0):

The deafult behaviousr of an anchor link is to jump to another document. Also the PHP code `$_GET['pedit_id']` is supposed to be executed when the request reaches the server. Here you are preventing the default behaviour of the anchor link, hence no request is sent to server. Though if you need to access the query string value you could do that with jQuery itself.

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
    if(QS.length>0){
        var val = QS[1].split('=');

        if(val.length>0){
          $("#edititems").html(val[1]).hide().slideDown('slow');
        }    
    }
});
```

Updated part for user:

If you want to load the product based on the url param, then there is not need of the above parsing. You could simply try

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var url =  $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax( url )
        .done(function(response) {
                 $("#edititems").html(response).hide().slideDown('slow');
        })
        .fail(function() {
              alert( "error" );
       });
});
```

See Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VEa7/)

Comment: $(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
    
    if(QS.length>0){
        var val = QS[1].split('=');
        if(val.length>0){
document.getElementById("val").value=val[1];
          $("#edititems").hide().slideDown('slow');

        }    
    }
});$prdid="<input type='hidden' id='val'>"; $qry=mysql_query("select * from products where id=$prdid"); is the above twophp statments are valid if not how can i do that

Comment: You want to load product, right? For that  you can send an AJAX request to retrieve the product details. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Am using to edit the product with in the same page i used a div tag under dat i had a form which is display:none initially when i click on edit it should diplay. I vll send u some more details now

Comment: <a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=1' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=2' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=3' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=4' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>


//Div which holds php statements that echo outs some values   

<DIV id='edit_inven' style="display:none">
//Here i had a edit form related to the products
</DIV>

Comment: $(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
    alert(QS.length)
    if(QS.length>0){
        var val = QS[1].split('=');
        alert(val)
        if(val.length>0){
          $("#edititems").html(val[1]).hide().slideDown('slow');
        }    
    }
}); U suggested me to use this how is it possible i should get that jquery effect also

Comment: send an ajax call with in the if(val.length) condition and show the response.  `if(val.length>0){ $.ajax({ type:'POST',url:'http://yoururl',data:'prd_id='+val[1],success:function(data){ $("#edititems").html(data).hide().slideDown('slow'); }); }`

Comment: Query string is appearing in the URL but the Div which i used for form is not displaying and the effect also not happeng